# T-SQL Order By on key-value table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables like :

Docs {#DocId, SomeData}
KeyValues {#RowId, DocId,  Name,  Value}

and it have values like :

**Docs**

```
D1 | This is content of doc 1

D2 | This is content of doc 2
```

**Key-values**

```
1 | D1 | Firstname | David

2 | D1 | Lastname  | Andersson

3 | D2 | Firstname | Anders

4 | D2 | Lastname  | Andersson
```

I would like to get Doc.SomeData and **order by the value of Firstname**

How-would you do it? Pivot? Joins?

**EDITED**
I might have simplified to much. The KeyValue table has the value divided into several columns, but the actual column to get the value is defined in C# code where the SQL is generated on the fly:

KeyValues {#RowId, DocId,  Name,  StringValue, IntegerNumericValue, FractalNumericValue, BoolValue, GuidValue, DateTimeValue}

Using Left Joins would need me to issue one left join for each sorting expression otherwise the set might get duplication of docs in the result.

Comment: So you want to sort data on any column dynamically based on passed value from c# code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the comments to the Gist for the solution. Any tweaks are highly appreciated.

https://gist.github.com/1343449#comments

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT SomeData 
FROM Doc d
INNER JOIN KeyValues k ON d.DocId = k.DocId AND k.Name = 'FirstName'
ORDER BY k.Value
```

**UPDATE :** 
If your sorting needs dynamically based on values passed from c# code then you can use case in order by clause like :

```
SELECT SomeData 
FROM Doc d
INNER JOIN KeyValues k ON d.DocId = k.DocId AND k.Name = @PassedValue
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @PassedValue = 'FirstName' THEN k.StringValue
              WHEN @PassedValue = 'LastName' THEN k.StringValue
              WHEN @PassedValue = 'Date' THEN k.DateTimeValue
              ELSE k.StringValue 
              END
```

Comment: That would not return a dock of Firstname don't exists for it. But, yes it could be solved with a left join, but I don't want the contents of the KeyValues with in the set returned. Just want to use it for sorting.

Comment: Can you please describe problem in detail ? sorry but I am not getting you from your comment. It will return only SomeData not any field from keyvalues table.

Comment: I've updated the question with more info. Look there and then I hope you realize what I mean.

Comment: @Daniel : Check my updated answer if it fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Still that would solve sort on one filed at the time. FirstName DESC and LastName ASC in same query would need two joins one for FirstName and one for LastName, and again. Not inner join. Hence, why I would see more of a pivot version or something like that.

Comment: @Daniel - So why is this information about needing to sort on multiple columns buried in the comments rather than in the example in your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Doc.SomeData, KV.Value
FROM Doc JOIN KeyValues KV ON Doc.DocId = KV.DocId
WHERE KV.Name = 'Firstname'
ORDER BY KV.Value
```